# How to create nested PHP array from simple multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP array as follows

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Main Category
            [parent_id] => null
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => sub category
            [parent_id] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => child category
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Main category 1
            [parent_id] => null
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => sub category 1
            [parent_id] => 4
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => child category 1
            [parent_id] => 5
        )

)
```

and I want this array to be converted as below using PHP

```
$categories = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'Name' => "Main Category",
        'sub' => array(
            id => 2,
            'Name' => 'Sub Category',
            'sub' => array(
                'id' => 3,
                'Name' => 'Child category',
                'sub' => 'None',
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'Name' => "Main Category 1",
        'sub' => array(
            id => 5,
            'Name' => 'Sub Category 1',
            'sub' => array(
                'id' => 6,
                'Name' => 'Child category 1',
                'sub' => 'None',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Actually I have a 3 level list hierarchy that looks something like this

```
A 1 level
 B 2 level under A
 C 2 level under A
   D level 3 under C

E 1 level
F 1 level 
  G 2 level under F
```

If provided information is not enough please ask me any question in comment. So the final output for my given example will look as below

Main category
  sub category
    child

Main category 1
  sub category 2
    child category 3

Here is what I tried.

```
foreach ($categoryList as $key => $value) {
            if ($value->getCategoryId()!=1) {
                $category[$key]['id'] = $value->getCategoryId();
                $category[$key]['name'] = $value->getName();
//                $category[$key]['parent_id'] = $value->getParentCategoryIds();
                $category[$key]['sub'] = $this->createSubCategoryArray($value->getCategoryId(), $categoryList);
            }
        }


 public function createSubCategoryArray($parentCatId, $categoryList)
        {
            foreach ($categoryList as $key => $category) {
                if($category->getCategoryId() == $parentCatId && $category->getCategoryId()!=1){
                    echo "string";
                    return array(
                        'id' => $category->getCategoryId(),
                        'name' => $category->getName(),
                        'sub' => $this->createSubCategoryArray($category->getCategoryId(), $categoryList)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you have tried so far. Post your attempts ?

Comment: What I tried if I send then persons who are looking to answer they might get confuse so didnt posted that, but if you need have a look on it but that doesnt mean you should down vote my question. My question has enough information to understand it and even I have given examples too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this and can modify it as per your requirement

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){

    if( $arr[$i]['parent_id'] == null ){
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $arr[$i]['id'],
            'Name' => $arr[$i]['name'],
            'sub' => array()
        );
    }elseif( $arr[$i]['parent_id'] != null){
        for($j=0;$j<count($data);$j++){
            if( $data[$j]['id'] == $arr[$i]['parent_id'] ){
                $data[$j]['sub'][] = createChild($arr[$i]); 
            }else{
                for($k=0;$k<count($data[$j]['sub']);$k++){
                    if($data[$j]['sub'][$k]['id'] == $arr[$i]['parent_id']){
                        $data[$j]['sub'][$k]['sub'] = createChild($arr[$i]);    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function createChild($obj){
    return array(
        'id' => $obj['id'],
        'name' => $obj['name'],
        'parent_id' => $obj['parent_id'],
        'sub' => array()
    );
}
```