# Multilevel tree with PHP

Tags: php, foreach, tree

I have one table of folders
We dont know the depth of array and first I am trying to take all folder with parentid 0 and then am again calling the same function in foreach so that iterates each folder. Below is the dummy table

```
    Id parentid label
    -- -------- ------
    1   0        ABC
    2   1        XYZ
    3   2        ABC2
    4   0        DUMMY
```

I am trying to make tree with below code:

```
 public function getFolder($parentId = null)
 {
     if(IS_NULL($parentId)){
         $parentId = 0;
     }
     $folders = Connection::queryBuilder()->select('f.id,f.parentid,f.label')
                ->from('folders','f')
                ->where('parentid='.$parentId)->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $temp = array();
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        $subfolders = self::getFolder($folder->id,$temp);
        array_push($temp,$folder,$subfolders);
    }

    return $temp;
}
```

But I am not getting the array the way I want. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you mean, "But i am **not** getting the array I want"

Comment: Please include the code of *getReportDocumentsByFolder*.

Comment: can you give a sample array of how you want your final array's structure to be like?

Comment: @trincot sorry i change the name here getReportDocumentsByFolder is same as getFolder. I trying to call it inside here also for recursive

Comment: you can fix your original question by clicking the _edit_ link

Comment: are you trying to create a multidimensional array?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create a multidimensional array with parent child relation. Child should be under parent

Comment: Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

There was a very close question: [How to created nested multi dimensional array from database result array with parent id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127572/how-to-created-nested-multi-dimensional-array-from-database-result-array-with-pa/35128941#35128941)

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// ordered by parent
$src = array(
    ['cid'=>'1','name'=>'Rootcat','parent'=>'0'],
    ['cid'=>'3','name'=>'dddd','parent'=>'1'],
    ['cid'=>'4','name'=>'test1','parent'=>'3'],
    ['cid'=>'5','name'=>'Test123 rec','parent'=>'3'],
    ['cid'=>'6','name'=>'abceg','parent'=>'3'],
    ['cid'=>'7','name'=>'JHGSGF','parent'=>'5'],
);
// inverse array, better take it sorted by parent_id desc
$data = array_reverse($src,false);
$for_parent = [];

foreach($data as $rec) {
    if (isset($for_parent[$rec['cid']])) {
        $rec['sub'] = $for_parent[$rec['cid']];
        unset($for_parent[$rec['cid']]);
    }
    $for_parent[$rec['parent']] [$rec['cid']]= $rec; 
}

print_r($for_parent);
```

So you can create array without recursive function.

Comment: This is nice, and I don't understand why someone would downvote this.

Comment: Well, you need to do some adaptations of course to your situation. Did you do that? Or did you just copy paste and run??

Comment: Update your query to result be ordered by parentid DESC. Then use my foreach iteration changing $data to $folders and your object properties. It must work ;)